# C# code jumps to uncalled function upon completion of another function in asp .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Background:**

I have a place in my webpage where the user can submit an ID number. They can either enter the ID into a textbox or select a heavily used ID from the drop down list. Since these two sources of input essentially do the same thing, I use the same callback function for both of them. There are checks in this function to see whether the sender was the textbox or the drop down (and appropriate validation checking).

**The Problem:**

I'm getting some very strange behavior from this function. When this function is called and the sender is the drop down list, everything works as it is supposed to. However, when this function is called and the sender is the text box, everything appears to be fine up until it is time to exit the function. Once the function has exited, control immediately jumps to another unrelated function that I have not called anywhere inside that function. It makes this jump both on the web when I test it and in the debugger. It always jumps to the same function. This function is itself a callback function for a push button somewhere else on the page (that is only being called when the user explicitly presses the button).

I do not know of any reason why it would be doing this and cannot figure out what is going wrong.

**Relevant Code**

Note: both the textbox and drop down list are in the EditItemTemplate of a GridView, if that matters.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxCQ" runat="server" BackColor="#ffcccc" Text="Enter CQ here" onclick="$(this).val('');" OnTextChanged="cq_Selected_In_Edit"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="AssociatedCQList" runat="server" BackColor="#ffcccc" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Font-Size="Smaller" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_CQList" DataTextField="cqdetail" DataValueField="cqID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cq_Selected_In_Edit">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Enabled="true" Value="Select from list of CQ's">Select from list of CQ's </asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void cq_Selected_In_Edit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object type = sender.GetType();
        string name = ((System.Reflection.MemberInfo)(type)).Name;
        bool isTextbox = (name == "TextBox"); // to be used throughout the function
        GridViewRow Row;
        string text;
        if (isTextbox) // it's the textbox calling
        {
            Row = (GridViewRow)((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(sender)).NamingContainer;
            text = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(sender)).Text;
        }
        else // it's the dropdown calling
        {
            Row = (GridViewRow)((System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)(sender)).NamingContainer;
            text = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl)(sender)).Text;
        }
        // do more processing, etc etc
    }
```

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing the relevant code, please edit the question.

Comment: How many buttons are there on the page, and how is the textbox callback being triggered?

Comment: From [How To: Respond to Changes in a TextBox Web Server Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2589b44c(v=vs.110).aspx) - "By default, the TextChanged event does not immediately cause the Web Forms page to be posted to the server. Instead, the event is raised in server code the next time the form is posted. " By observation, your code doesn't use `AutoPostback` on the textbox control which means that *something else* is causing the form to be posted. Which I posit is (whether you intended it to or not) that button being invoked.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever within the grid, there are linkbuttons in 4 columns, and there are 20 rows to a page. So there are 80 linkbuttons on the page, but only 4 distinct functions there. Then there is one push button on the page that "resets" the page (as the linkbuttons filter the entries by various things), and that is what is mysteriously being called.

Comment: Link buttons are rendered in HTML as anchor tags. You have a form which has only a single (HTML) button and so if you're pressing enter after filling in the text box then the form will auto-submit with the only possible button being pressed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am not able to test it right now as I am not at work, but I am almost sure that this is the correct reason. Would setting the AutoPostback property of the textbox to true remedy this? Must a button always be pressed when someone presses enter after typing into a text box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know exactly what *causes* this, although it appears to have something to do with the fact that textboxes have an affinity for wanting to press buttons.

What fixed the issue was placing the textbox in a panel, and then have the panel press an invisible button which called the code behind function (of course, slight modifications were also needed in the code behind). A simple implementation is shown below:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
    <asp:TextBox id="txtSearch" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button id="btnSearch" runat="server" text="Start search" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Code Source: [How can I fire a Button Click event when Enter Key is pressed based on what textbox has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248434/how-can-i-fire-a-button-click-event-when-enter-key-is-pressed-based-on-what-text?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The `ID` of the control is `TextBoxQC` and you're comparing that against `TextBox` in order to find the correct object. This is evaluating to false because the 2 strings are not equal.

As you want to use the code throughout, change it to

```
bool isTextbox = (name.Contains("TextBox"));
```

As the function suggests it is checking that the string contains the text `TextBox`.

Comment: This isn't correct, my bool evaluates properly. I am getting the name of the calling control (ie, what it actually is), not getting the ID of the control.